Clock Dial Puzzle
I am working on a puzzle where I need to fill 4 wheels with segments. The first 3 wheels are already complete which helps understand the direction in which the segments are moving. For the last wheel, I can't figure out my mistake, and apparently, only one section is wrong.
Rules:
If a line passes through multiple points, it must be split into several segments (except for diagonals).
I am sharing the 3 validated wheels and my attempt at the fourth wheel.



Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

all lines pass through multiple points. i don't see how any of your "validated" wheels show lines split into segments. Can you circle things in your images to explain more? Maybe show an example of something invalid (and why) ?

@KateGregory I agree that the description is confusing. I think this is actually a [tag:sequence] puzzle . Each shape follows a logical progression in the first three wheels, and we have to work out where they should be in the fourth.

E.g. The diamond at the top of the north-west quadrant has all its vertices moving one point toward the centre on each step, so it keeps its shape. The triangle below moves one point counter-clockwise each step, while its upper vertex also moves one point toward the centre each step. The bottom shape in that quadrant isn't moving, but appears to grow a new point on each step. Etc.


 I think what you are missing is the stroke marked in red in the image below. That stroke appears only in the second wheel, so I think it’s a blinking stroke which appears and disappears in alternate wheels.

